# how to rollback last update sql query i did

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE ProductSerial 
SET BranchID=2
WHERE BranchID=4 
AND ActivatedSystems=0 
AND CustomerID=1 
AND ProductID=19
```

this is the query I have to run.....instead of that i did..

```
UPDATE ProductSerial SET BranchID=2

UPDATE ProductSerial SET BranchID=2 
WHERE BranchID=4 
AND ActivatedSystems=0 
AND CustomerID=1 
AND ProductID=19
```

this is the query i have to run.....instead of that i did..

```
UPDATE ProductSerial SET BranchID=2
```

it my online db.....i have to recover it from previous stage....

Comment: If you had a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, just do a `ROLLBACK` and you're fine. If you didn't use a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, then restore the backup I'm sure you took **before** running this query .....

Comment: if you are saying you have already done this, and are looking to recover data, and don't have a backup, then you are almost certainly out of luck. You should, however, tell us what database platform you are using, just in case there is some implementation specific trick (there almost certainly isn't in my experience)

Comment: Need more information, what kind of database are you using and what kind of client are you using (some clients perform autocommits)?

Comment: i am using sql 2008R2 ...no back up...it online db....any trick to get it back ....

Comment: @Taja_100 In the biz we use a trick called "regular backups". If you don't have those, and your database is in `FULL` recovery mode and you can leverage the log file to recover the data.

Comment: Maybe you can figure out a way of finding what products are available at each branch? And write a new script to re-apply branchIDs. Otherwise I think you are out of luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
begin transaction

// execute SQL code here

rollback transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ROLLBACK
```

to rollback your changes. Depending on the client you're using, this will work fine.

If the client you're using has an "AUTOCOMMIT" feature that you turned on, then you're out of luck, as your changes were already commited. The only option then is to restore from backup (or use the MSSQL "Oracle Flashback" equivalent [if there is such a thing, I have no idea]).